# Complex valued function limit using polar coordinates

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}$ be defined by
$$f(z)=\dfrac{|z|^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{3i\text{arg}(z)}-1}{|z|e^{2i\text{arg}(z)}-1}.$$
Considering polar coordinates I need to determine the following limit:
$$\lim\limits_{(r,\theta)\to(1,0)}\dfrac{r^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{3i\theta}-1}{re^{2i\theta}-1}.$$
Note there is a singularity when $z=1$, that is when $(r,\theta)=(1,0)$.

I was wondering if there is some form of L'Hopital's rule that may be used here, or if there is some other trick that I can currently not see. I believe the limit should be 3/2, but I have no way of showing this. Any hints or advise would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's set $a=e^{i\theta}$, so that the limit can be written as
\begin{align}
  &\lim_{(r,a)\to(1,1)}\frac{r^{3/2}a^3-1}{ra^2-1}=\\
  &\quad=\lim_{(r,a)\to(1,1)}\frac{(r^{3/2}a^3-1)(r^{3/2}a^3+1)}{(ra^2-1)(r^{3/2}a^3+1)}=\\
  &\quad=\lim_{(r,a)\to(1,1)}\frac{r^3a^6-1}{2(ra^2-1)}=\\
  &\quad=\lim_{(r,a)\to(1,1)}\frac{(ra^2-1)(r^2a^4+ra^2+1)}{2(ra^2-1)}=\\
  &\quad=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{(r,a)\to(1,1)}(r^2a^4+ra^2+1)=\frac{3}{2}\\
\end{align}

Comment: How did you calculate the denominator in the third line? The rest follows clearly, I just cannot see how you obtained this line. Or did you apply algebra of limits and substitute into this expression $(r,a)=(1,1)$?

Comment: @George The factor $(r^3/2a^3+1)$ has been substituted with $2$, because in a product, if a factor does not go to $0$ or $\infty$, can be substituted.